# MySQL Datatypes Reinserting values

Tags: mysql, text, longtext

Ive been meaning to ask this one.

I have a table which contains a TEXT datatype. Ive inserted a value in it and try to output and it works. The next thing i did was to insert again with bigger values size. As i tried to output it dont work anymore. I tried to change TEXT to LONGTEXT and tried to output it but no luck. I reinsert the value and it works now in LONGTEXT. My question is

Is there a way that I wouldnt have to reinsert the bigger value size and output it the first time I save it? Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (LONGTEXT is perhaps MySQL?)

Comment: Ive been using MySQL sir

Comment: Correct tags will give your question better attention!

Comment: oh! sorry my bad. Appreciate it

Comment: No problem at all! We're all here to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like that. Had you get any warning during insert in Text column?

When we don't use **STRICT_ALL_TABLES** strict mode for MySQL, our query execute successfully with warnings only which generally we ignore.  So my recommendation is to use **STRICT_ALL_TABLES** strict mode. Then You'll get exact error while inserting any new row or updating data.

if you are getting any warning. Please check with below query you'll get more insights

> show warnings;